# Uploading 25 GB file to a dedicated server takes long time

Tags: file, http, upload, cloud, scp

I'm in a situation where I've to automate the operation of uploading 25 files with sizes of 1 GB each.

I have an Ubuntu machine that contains 25 files with sizes of 1 GB each, I should write a script to automate the operation of uploading the files each day to Godday's dedicated server.

I've tried these ways:

1. Using normal HTTP client-server APIs each file takes too much time about 30 minutes.
2. Using FTP client-server each file takes too much time about 25 minutes.
3. Using the SCP tool also takes a long time to upload one file.

I've tried uploading a 1 GB file to Google Drive to make sure that my internet speed is good, it takes just one minute.

What is the best approach to solving that?